# Using EvaluateXpath in nifi

Tags: xml, xpath, apache-nifi

I have xml response like this :

```
<Result xmlns="olineservice" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<ResponseStatus>false</ResponseStatus>
<Error>
<ErrorCode>-7</ErrorCode>
<ErrorDescription>data  wasn't  found</ErrorDescription>
</Error>
</Result>
```

and I wan to get  value of `ErrorCode`. I tried  this:

```
//Error[1]/text()
```

but `ErrorCode`  attribute  seems  to be `Nan`.

Can you recommend me any solution?

Answer (score 2):

To specifically get the error code:

```
//Error[1]/ErrorCode/text()
```

To specifically get the error description:

```
//Error[1]/ErrorDescription/text()
```

These values are all being read as text in this way, so you can read as a number:

```
//Error[1]/ErrorCode/number()
```